# Add M2M field using create(): Django

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a lot of doubts about managing the M2m field, I finally got a solution to add that data to a model, but there are still some issues, give me a solution to overcome this,

```
class CourseListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    instructors = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    image = FileField()
    keyarea = CourseKeyAreaSerializer
    subject = CourseSubjectsSerializer
    sections = serializers.ListField(write_only=True)
    beneficiaries = serializers.ListField(write_only=True)
    section = CourseSectionSerializers
    beneficiary = CourseBeneficiarySerializer

    def create(self, validated_data):
        data = validated_data
        try:
            new = Course.objects.create(image=data['image'], name=data['name'], description=data['description'], is_free=data['is_free'],
                                        keyarea=data['keyarea'], subject=data['subject'])
            new.save()

            beneficiary_data = data['beneficiaries']
            new.beneficiary.set(*[beneficiary_data])
            section_data = data['sections']
            new.section.set(*[section_data])

            return new
        except Exception as e:
            e = "invalid data"
            return e
```

here first creating the "new" object after that to set the M2M field like

```
"new.beneficiary.set(*[beneficiary_data])"
```

but is there any way to add beneficiary and section like this

```
   "new = Course.objects.create(image=data['image'],name=data['name'], description=data['description'],is_free=data['is_free'],....)"
```

Comment: Exactly *what* errors?

Comment: actually there is no error, i want to add m2m field value to the model using create() along with "new" object or any other way to add an m2m field value to a model